# Redundant blank line in query result

Tags: oracle

I have this sql:

```
with p_1 as
(
    select 1 sorszam, 'X1' tipus from dual
    union all select 2 sorszam, 'X2' tipus from dual
    union all select 3 sorszam, 'X3' tipus from dual
)
select (
    (case when p1.sorszam=1 then ('[' || chr(13) || chr(10)) else '' end) || 
    p1.tipus 
    || (case when p1.sorszam=(select max(sorszam) from p_1) then (chr(13) || chr(10) || ']') else '' end)
    ) szoveg
from p_1 p1
order by p1.sorszam
```

The result is:

```
SZOVEG
--------
[
X1

X2
X3
]
```

My question is: why is there a blank line after the first line?

Comment: Are you sure you are using "Microsoft SQL Server"? SQL Server does not support using the standard string concatenation operator `||`

Comment: I think this is `Oracle`.

Comment: Thanks! My full version desciption is:

Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production                             
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production                                          
CORE 10.2.0.3.0 Production                                                      
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production                         
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: I have the solution: "Set recsep off"

Thanks for the trouble, Saina!

Comment: Please post your solution as answer, or consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SET RECSEP OFF` removes the record separator.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699269